# how to combine objects in an array that have the same key in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have an array of objects where i want to reduce the number of objects based on the common date property in javascript

**Sample input:**

```
const data = [
    {date:"1 Nov", foo: 123},
    {date:"1 Nov", bar: 456},
    {date:"2 Nov", foo: 234}, 
    {date:"2 Nov", bar: 567}
];
```

**Expected output**

```
const data = [
    {date:"1 Nov", foo: 123, bar: 456},
    {date:"2 Nov", foo: 234, bar: 567}, 
];
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? You should try to do it and if your code doesn't work, then ask question and share you code to helping you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge duplicate keys in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789634/how-can-i-merge-duplicate-keys-in-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the [`Array#reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve this, seeing that the expected output is an aggregation of the input array. One way to apply this method might be;

1. for each iteration of the input array, check the current output array result (ie `result` as shown below) for any items that have a date matching the current `item`
2. if a match is found, then "spread" the found object into the existing object with matching "date" (ie combine the key/values of both objects into a single new object), and assign this back into the `result` array
3. otherwise, if a match is not found, simply add the current item to the result array as-is

The following shows this description in code - hope this helps!

```js
const data = [
    {date:"1 Nov", foo: 123},
    {date:"1 Nov", bar: 456},
    {date:"2 Nov", foo: 234}, 
    {date:"2 Nov", bar: 567}
];

const output = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  
  const i = result.findIndex(resultItem => resultItem.date === item.date)
    
  if(i === -1) {
    // No item in current result array found that matches the date of item
    // so add item to result array
    result.push(item)
  }
  else {
    // An item found with date matching item in current result so combine 
    // the two into a new object and assign this back into our result 
    // array
    result[i] = { ...result[i], ...item }
  }
  
  return result
}, [])

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative using lodash. I would like to include it just as an alternative.

```js
const data = [
  {date:"1 Nov", foo: 123},
  {date:"1 Nov", bar: 456},
  {date:"2 Nov", foo: 234}, 
  {date:"2 Nov", bar: 567}
];

const result = _.map(
  _.groupBy(data, 'date'), 
  (d) => 
    _.reduce(
      d,
      (result, value) => Object.assign(result, value),
      {}
    )
)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```